# Как удалить свойство :before для первого элемента?

Tags: css, style, content

```
#tag:before{content:'✦';} эта звездочка разделяет тэги, с первого ее нужно убрать

<div id="tags">
{block:HasTags}
{block:Tags}<div id="tag">
<a href="{TagURL}">{Tag}</a></div>
{/block:Tags}
{/block:HasTags}    
</div>
```

Comment: а у Вас, что, все теги идут с одним id="tag"?

Comment: да, там для всех тегов одно и то же оформление

Comment: id должен быть уникальным на странице - запрещено использовать один и тот же идентификатор 2 и более раз. одинаковое оформление надо задавать через классы